# How can i extract the fieldnames and values from Django query

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Suppose i have this model

```
class Model():
          var1      = models.TextField()
          var2      = models.FloatField()
          var3      = models.FloatField()
          var4      = models.FloatField()
```

Now I want to have one template which i can use for all models. My requirement is

> 1. I want to display var1 , var2 , var 4 in view not var 3
> 2. In the template , i don't want to hard code field names like var1 ,
>      var2, var3 which i will make the
>      heading of table , so i would like
>      like to get that from array
> 3. I want all the data corresponding to those vars

Basically i want something like

`Object_List` which contains the `field names` and `field values` both for `all rows` in DB table

`Object_List` -- I will grab form `SELECT var1, var2, var4 from table`

so that in template i can use

```
{% for field in Object_List.fields %}
  <th>{{ field }}</th> 
 {% endfor %}
```

Then for data i can use

```
 {% for object in Object_List.objects %}
            <tr>
            {% for field in object %}
                 <td>{{ value }}</td> 
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

I am not sure if i explained it clearly . is it possible to achieve something like that.
The main requirement is that i want only selected fields to display in template not all fields mentioned in Model

Comment: You haven't really explained it clearly, I'm afraid. Where do you want to specify which fields to display?

Comment: IN the query for.e,g in raw sql  `select var1,var2 , var4 from table` so that i only get fields which i require

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like the obvious way to do this is to use a `values` query:

```
objects = Model.objects.values('var1', 'var2', 'var4')
```

This gives you a list of dictionaries, each one mapping field name to field value. So you can get your header row from the first of these:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <th>
       {% for fieldname in object.keys %}<td>{{ fieldname }}</td>{% endfor %}
    </th>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
      {% for value in object.values %}<td>{{ value }}</td>{% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you are champ buddy, that worked perfectly fine. If i want all rows can i use vsame function or i have to use .all(). because i have tried your loop with objects.all() and it was not working as it returned the queryset

Comment: My example does give you all rows - if you want to filter the rows, just add `.filter(whatever=whatever)` in the normal way. If you meant all columns, you can use an empty `values()` call.

Comment: Actually i mean all columns , Values() will be fine. Thanks for you help again